# Identify form control id in Drupal 7 Forms API

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, form-api

Does form controls in Forms API have id's? Below is my sample code:

```
function myid_user_page_form(){  
    $form = array();
    $form['id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('ID Information'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );  
    $form['id']['myphoto_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button', 
        '#value' => '...',
        '#attributes' => array(
        'onclick' => "myphoto_options();",),  
    );
    return $form;
 }
```

Sorry for this very simple beginner's question but how to identify my button's id in the sample above(e.g) $form['id']['myphoto_button']?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been [cross-posted on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146357/identify-form-control-id-in-drupal-7-forms-api)

Answer (score 0):

The [`#attributes`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) property is used to set html attributes for the element. (Like, id, class, style, onclick, etc.)

I can see that you are using it to bind `onclick` handler. So, it order to give your button an id:

```
$form['id']['myphoto_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button', 
    '#value' => '...',
    '#attributes' => array(
        'onclick' => "myphoto_options();",
        'id'      => 'YOUR-BUTTON-ID',
    ),  
);
```